# PDF Fonts - Text Field Properties

Tags: pdf

Does anyone happen to know how to change the list of fonts at the top of your font optioins in Acrobat Text Field Properties?

[image: Screen shot]

It has been bugging me for a while. I would like to put different fonts at the top of the list to streamline my work when selecting the fonts I wish to use when preparing forms in Acrobat. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You dont really have the option to do that, contact Adobe. The best you can do is rename the font inside the font file, but realistically speaking that is not an option.

Another alternative is to use the Acrobat API and make your own dialog.